# Evaluation of a recommendation system. How can I do that?

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, recommender-system

I'm learning to make a book recommendation system but I am facing some difficulties to evaluate the model. I chose the collaborative filtering item based strategy. The dataset is a matrix (book, user) filled with the ratings of the books. The dataset is something like:

```
        user_a user_b user_c  ... user_x
book_1    0     3      5     ...  4
book_2    2     1      0     ...  0
book_3    0     0      0     ...  2
...
```

Bellow the code to train the model.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
model = NearestNeighbors(metric='cosine', algorithm='brute')
model.fit(dataset)

# get the index of a book that contains 'harry potter' in its name
title = 'Harry Potter'
mask = books['title'].str.contains(title)
book_isbn = books[mask]['isbn']
mask = X.index.isin(book_isbn)
book_reference = X[mask].head(1)

# find the 5 nearest books from 'harry potter'
k = 5
distances, indices = model.kneighbors(book_reference.values, n_neighbors=k+1)
```

Well, the thing is 'kneighbors()' function is returning the distances of the 5 nearest vectors(books) from 'book_reference' and their indices. I don't know how evaluate the performance of this model since its not making predictions. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [specialized metrics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351963/how-good-is-my-recommender/351982#351982) for recommender systems like [Mean Percentage Ranking (MPR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462470/how-can-i-evaluate-the-implicit-feedback-als-algorithm-for-recommendations-in-ap/46490352#46490352) and [Mean Reciprocal Rank (MRR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_reciprocal_rank) and [variations of the regular classification metrics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/25102/35989) like [Precision@$k$ or Recall@$k$](https://medium.com/@m_n_malaeb/recall-and-precision-at-k-for-recommender-systems-618483226c54). You should look into those.